# Display grid next to a set of radio boxes depending on the radio box selected

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ext-js 4 and stuck on the following. I have a form with 6 radio buttons. Based on the button selected I want to display a grid right next to the form. How can this be done?

e.g: Radio buttons: All, time, priority.

If All is selected by users, it displays time and priority both information.

If time selected then only  time information in the grid and so on.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide or show columns in your grid:

myGrid.getColumnModel().setHidden(0, true); // hide column 0 (0 = the first column).

If you are asking about two (or maybe more than 2) different grids, you can add them both with different properties "hidden' and then use:
gridPanel.hide() and gridPanel.show().

To display grid right next to the form you can use column layout.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

Comment: Thanks Svetlana, that helped a lot.